# MYSQL: subquery into a table updated in the main query

Tags: mysql

I'd like do something like this:

1. In table TAGS find a row with name='someName', and remeber it's id
2. In the same table find another row with someCondition and set in this row col refference=the id from above

Tried to do this using a subquery, but mysql refused saying I can't subquery a table that I'm updating in the main query.

How can I otherwise implement the above idea?

Thank  you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this

```
    update TAGS set 
    reference = 
        (select my_id from 
            (select id as my_id from TAGS where name='someName') 
         as SUB_TAGS) 
    where someCondition;
```

Not advisable though.

---

**Edit#1** You can avoid the sub-queries altogether -- as [taspeotis rightly mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636440/mysql-subquery-into-a-table-updated-in-the-main-query/4636479#4636479), by `join`ing the same table with the criteria. Here goes the code for that:

```
  UPDATE 
    TAGS t1, TAGS t2 
  SET 
    t1.reference = t2.id
  WHERE
        t2.name = 'someName' 
    AND
        t1.someField = someCondition;
```

This is a better approach.

Comment: I guess the double nesting to workaround the very issue that mysql reported me? and why not advisable?

Comment: Use of temporary table is not advisable -- and that's what exactly I am doing here. Temp tables has unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @gidireich wow, was my tribal knowledge wrong? I do not see much articles on performance overhead of temp tables in mySQL while Googling around.

Comment: @gidireich well someone suggest to avoid nested queries :) http://www.selikoff.net/2008/12/10/memo-avoid-nested-queries-in-mysql-at-all-costs/ But this is pretty much "the" solution as you wanted.

Comment: This worked, thank you. Can you explain what was the problem and *how* what you proposed solved it?

Answer (score 1):

[Convert your subquery to a join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/rewriting-subqueries.html) and then `UPDATE`:

> You can also perform UPDATE operations covering multiple tables. However, you cannot use ORDER BY or LIMIT with a multiple-table UPDATE. The table_references clause lists the tables involved in the join. Its syntax is described in Section 12.2.8.1, “JOIN Syntax”. Here is an example:

```
UPDATE items,month SET items.price=month.price
WHERE items.id=month.id;
The preceding example shows an inner join that uses the comma operator, but multiple-table
```

> UPDATE statements can use any type of join permitted in SELECT statements, such as LEFT JOIN.